# Intersecting two lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

How can we make 2 lines that meet each other (sitting on top of another), intersect each other in QGIS? How can we make a point between them?

[image]

The reason why I want to make an intersection is that I want to make routing work. (I want the route to go through that point instead of taking longer rotues.)

Comment: The tool in Vector --> Analysis Tool --> Line Intersection should do the work you want

Comment: @matteo The Line Intersection tool creates a new layer, and it analyzes all the intersection in the entire layer. Is there a way would to do it on just particular lines and on the same layer? Thank you.

Comment: what about selecting the lines yu want and run the Line Intersection algorithm in the Processing Toolbox? It takes into account only your selection

Comment: @matteo I tried selecting the lines I want and use the tool, but it ended up like this, http://puu.sh/kkcpc/61feb0b45a.png it still processes the whole vector layer and asking to save the output to another layer.

Comment: you have to use the Line Intersection algorithm through the Processing Toolbox.. if you have any selected features, Processing takes only these for the calculation

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to (1) break lines at the intersection, then (2) extract node.

(1) Break lines at the intersection

From QGIS Processing Toolbox, go to `GRASS GIS 7 | Vector` and activate **v.clean** tool. There are several options in `Cleaning tool` but please choose **break**.

(2) Extract node at the intersection

Again in the  `GRASS GIS 7 | Vector` tree, there is **v.net.articulation** tool. Start this tool and select the cleaned line layer (output from `v.clean`) as input layer.

QGIS has another tool to extract nodes (`Vector geometry tools | Extract nodes`), but this tool extract all vertices in the line layer... You'll end up with many unwanted points.